# Unity project working in editor but not in build

Tags: build, jobs

I'm new to unity and have been following the tutorials on CatlikeCoding.com. More specifically I'm at *basics*, *jobs* 4.6

I'm just now trying to do jobs and burst compilation. Everything works fine when running in unity but when I try and build the project I get the following error messages.

[image: Error messages]

Again, I am very new and these tutorials are so far my only experience with unity.

Any idea how I can get the project to run?
Also is there a way to upload the unity file and should I attempt to do that here?

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio installed + MSBuild?

Comment: @MaximilianAnzinger how do I check that?

Comment: Open the visual studio installer and check if MSBuild is checked under the components section.

Comment: @MaximilianAnzinger yeah I have MSBuild. I've also been able to build and run previously